# Unable to find Terraform extension in visual studio 2019 & 2022 preview version

Tags: terraform, visual-studio-2022

I am using VS2019 & VS2022 preview version, trying to add Terraform extension. Upon searching in the extension section (under online marketplace), unable to find terraform both in 2019 & 2022 version. Any other way to install Terraform extension to Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean Hashicorp Terraform?

Looks like they dont make an extension for full Visual Studio. You'll want to use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)